# Website insert character to Microsoft Word

Tags: javascript, ms-word, web

I build this website: (just a demo)

[Symbol Index](http://symbolindex.azurewebsites.net)

Summary the website:

> list all symbol character of a font, for quick-lookup and paste into docs, such as Microsoft Word.

**my teacher request:**

> He want to double click a symbol (in the website), and it will be inserted into the current opened doc (MS Word) instantly (not Ctrl+V)

How can I do that, thank you all.

Comment: I would immediately deinstall any browser where this is possible without my prior approval.

Comment: Yeah, I will uninstall any browsers which have so such that automation, too. This request of my teacher is too hard, seem like impossible.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure, but would assume this to be impossible for any major browser - at least without installing a plugin or doing some kind of approval form by the browser first. There are these "continue with app X" approval forms, like with discord or similar, but this all seems much more complex than control+V.

Comment: May be MS Word supported some APIs which can use from the browsers? Or at least Internet Explorer or Silverlight can?

Comment: I suppose it might be possible to create an add-in for Word that has a "listener" to something to which the web browser does have access. Write the information to that, then Word will pick it up from there. That's just pure theory on my part, though.

Comment: Thank you Cindy Meister. I'm going to try that.